# Inference error with TensorFlow C++ on iOS: "Invalid argument: Session was not created with a graph before Run()!"

Tags: c++, ios, tensorflow

I am trying to run my model on iOS using TensorFlow's C++ API. The model is a `SavedModel` saved as a `.pb` file. However, calls to `Session::Run()` result in the error:

> "Invalid argument: Session was not created with a graph before Run()!"

In Python, I can successfully run inference on the model with the following code:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, ['serve'], '/path/to/model/export')
    result = sess.run(['OutputTensorA:0', 'OutputTensorB:0'], feed_dict={
        'InputTensorA:0': np.array([5000.00] * 1000).reshape(1, 1000),
        'InputTensorB:0': np.array([300.00] * 1000).reshape(1, 1000)
    })
    print(result[0])
    print(result[1])
```

In C++ on iOS, I try to mimick this working snippit as follows:

```
tensorflow::Input::Initializer input_a(5000.00, tensorflow::TensorShape({1, 1000}));
tensorflow::Input::Initializer input_b(300.00, tensorflow::TensorShape({1, 1000}));

tensorflow::Session* session_pointer = nullptr;

tensorflow::SessionOptions options;
tensorflow::Status session_status = tensorflow::NewSession(options, &session_pointer);

std::cout << session_status.ToString() << std::endl; // prints OK

std::unique_ptr<tensorflow::Session> session(session_pointer);

tensorflow::GraphDef model_graph;

NSString* model_path = FilePathForResourceName(@"saved_model", @"pb");
PortableReadFileToProto([model_path UTF8String], &model_graph);

tensorflow::Status session_init = session->Create(model_graph);

std::cout << session_init.ToString() << std::endl; // prints OK

std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor> outputs;
tensorflow::Status session_run = session->Run({{"InputTensorA:0", input_a.tensor}, {"InputTensorB:0", input_b.tensor}}, {"OutputTensorA:0", "OutputTensorB:0"}, {}, &outputs);

std::cout << session_run.ToString() << std::endl; // Invalid argument: Session was not created with a graph before Run()!
```

The methods `FilePathForResourceName` and `PortableReadFileToProto` are taken from the TensorFlow iOS sample found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/ios/simple/RunModelViewController.mm).

What is the problem? I noticed that this happens regardless of how simple the model is ([see my issue report on GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13090)), which means the problem is not with the specifics of the model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary issue here is that you are exporting your graph to a [`SavedModel`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model) in Python but then reading it in as a [`GraphDef`](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/tool_developers/#graphdef) in C++. While both have a `.pb` extension and are similar, they are not equivalent.

What is happening is you are reading in the `SavedModel` with `PortableReadFileToProto()` and it is failing, leaving an empty pointer (`model_graph`) to a `GraphDef` object. So after the execution of `PortableReadFileToProto()`, `model_graph` remains an empty, but valid, `GraphDef`, which is why the error says *Session was not created with a graph before Run()*. `session->Create()` succeeds because you successfully created a session with an empty graph.

The way to check if `PortableReadFileToProto()` fails is to check its return value. It returns a bool, which will be 0 if reading in the graph failed. If you wish to obtain a descriptive error here, use [`ReadBinaryProto()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/cc/namespace/tensorflow#namespacetensorflow_1a79f05d00b536b44dcd07e3e63b642d72). Another way you can tell if reading the graph failed is by checking the value of `model_graph.node_size()`. If this is 0, then you have an empty graph and reading it in has failed.

While you can use TensorFlow's C API to perform inference on a `SavedModel` by using [`TF_LoadSessionFromSavedModel()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/66eed3646677dc7a8c8e94cd1936b45f6cb3609b/tensorflow/c/c_api.cc#L2223) and [`TF_SessionRun()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/66eed3646677dc7a8c8e94cd1936b45f6cb3609b/tensorflow/c/c_api.h#L1198), the recomended method is to export your graph to a frozen model using [`freeze_graph.py`](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/tool_developers/#Freezing) or write to a `GraphDef` using [`tf.train.write_graph()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/write_graph). I will demonstrate successful inference with a model exported using `tf.train.write_graph()`:

In Python:

```
# Build graph, call it g
g = tf.Graph()

with g.as_default():
    input_tensor_a = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, name="InputTensorA")
    input_tensor_b = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, name="InputTensorB")
    output_tensor_a = tf.stack([input_tensor_a], name="OutputTensorA")
    output_tensor_b = tf.stack([input_tensor_b], name="OutputTensorB")

# Save graph g
with tf.Session(graph=g) as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    tf.train.write_graph(
        graph_or_graph_def=sess.graph_def,
        logdir='/path/to/export',
        name='saved_model.pb',
        as_text=False
    )
```

In C++ (Xcode):

```
using namespace tensorflow;
using namespace std;

NSMutableArray* predictions = [NSMutableArray array];

Input::Initializer input_tensor_a(1, TensorShape({1}));
Input::Initializer input_tensor_b(2, TensorShape({1}));

SessionOptions options;
Session* session_pointer = nullptr;
Status session_status = NewSession(options, &session_pointer);
unique_ptr<Session> session(session_pointer);

GraphDef model_graph;
string model_path = string([FilePathForResourceName(@"saved_model", @"pb") UTF8String]);

Status load_graph = ReadBinaryProto(Env::Default(), model_path, &model_graph);

Status session_init = session->Create(model_graph);

cout << "Session creation Status: " << session_init.ToString() << endl;
cout << "Number of nodes in model_graph: " << model_graph.node_size() << endl;
cout << "Load graph Status: " << load_graph.ToString() << endl;

vector<pair<string, Tensor>> feed_dict = {
    {"InputTensorA:0", input_tensor_a.tensor},
    {"InputTensorB:0", input_tensor_b.tensor}
};

vector<Tensor> outputs;
Status session_run = session->Run(feed_dict, {"OutputTensorA:0", "OutputTensorB:0"}, {}, &outputs);

[predictions addObject:outputs[0].scalar<int>()];
[predictions addObject:outputs[1].scalar<int>()];

Status session_close = session->Close();
```

This general method will work, but you will likely experience issues with required operations missing from the TensorFlow library you built and therefore inference would still fail. To combat this, first make sure that you have built the latest [TensorFlow `1.3`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v1.3.0) by cloning the repo on your machine and running [`tensorflow/contrib/makefile/build_all_ios.sh`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/build_all_ios.sh) from the root `tensorflow-1.3.0` directory. It is unlikely that inference will work for a custom, non-canned model if you use the [`TensorFlow-experimental`](https://cocoapods.org/pods/TensorFlow-experimental) Pod like the examples. Once you have a static library built using `build_all_ios.sh`, you need to link it up in your `.xcconfig` by following the instructions [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/ios/).

Once you successfully link the static library built using the makefile with Xcode, you will likely still get errors that prevent inference. While the actual errors you will get depend on your implementation, you will receive errors that fall into two different forms:

1. > OpKernel ('op: "[operation]" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op:
   >   [operation]
2. > No OpKernel was registered to support Op '[operation]' with these
   >   attrs.  Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels: [...]

Error #1 means that the `.cc` file from `tensorflow/core/ops` or `tensorflow/core/kernels` for the corresponding operation (or closely associated operation) is not in the [`tf_op_files.txt`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/tf_op_files.txt) file in `tensorflow/contrib/makefile`. You will have to find the `.cc` that contains `REGISTER_OP("YourOperation")` and add it to `tf_op_files.txt`. You must rebuild by running `tensorflow/contrib/makefile/build_all_ios.sh` again.

Error #2 means that the `.cc` file for the corresponding operation is in your `tf_op_files.txt` file, but you have supplied the operation with a data type that it (a) doesn't support or (b) is stripped off to reduce the size of the build.

One "gotcha" is that if you are using `tf.float64` in the implementation of your model, this is exported as `TF_DOUBLE` in your `.pb` file and this is not supported by most operations. Use `tf.float32` in place of `tf.float64` and then re-save your model using `tf.train.write_graph()`.

If you are still receiving error #2 after checking you are providing the correct datatype to the operation, you will need to either remove `__ANDROID_TYPES_SLIM__` in the makefile located at `tensorflow/contrib/makefile` or replace it with `__ANDROID_TYPES_FULL__` and then rebuild.

After getting passed errors #1 and #2, you will likely have successful inference.

Answer (score 0):

One addition to the very comprehensive explanation above:

@jshapy8 is right in saying "You will have to find the .cc that contains REGISTER_OP("YourOperation") and add it to tf_op_files.txt" and there is a process that can simplify that a bit:

```
## build the print_selective_register_header tool. Run from tensorflow root
bazel build tensorflow/python/tools:print_selective_registration_header
bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/print_selective_registration_header \
--graphs=<path to your frozen model file here>/model_frozen.pb > ops_to_register.h
```

This creates a .h file that lists only the ops needed for your specific model.

Now when compiling your static libraries follow the **Build By Hand** instructions [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/makefile)

The instructions say to do the following:

```
make -f tensorflow/contrib/makefile/Makefile \
TARGET=IOS \
IOS_ARCH=ARM64
```

But you can pass a lot to the makefile specific to your needs and I've found the following your best bet:

```
make -f tensorflow/contrib/makefile/Makefile \
TARGET=IOS IOS_ARCH=ARM64,x86_64 OPTFLAGS="-O3 -DANDROID_TYPES=ANDROID_TYPES_FULL -DSELECTIVE_REGISTRATION -DSUPPORT_SELECTIVE_REGISTRATION"
```

In particular you are telling it here to compile for just two of the 5 architectures to speed up compiling time (full list is: i386 x86_64 armv7 armv7s arm64 and obviously takes longer) - IOS_ARCH=ARM64,x86_64 - and then you are telling it not to compile for ANDROID_TYPES_SLIM (which will give you the Float/Int casting issues referred to above) and then finally you are telling it to pull all the necessary ops kernel files and include them in the make process.

**Update** . Not sure why this wasn't working for me yesterday, but this is probably a cleaner and safer method:

```
build_all_ios.sh OPTFLAGS="-O3 -DANDROID_TYPES=ANDROID_TYPES_FULL -DSELECTIVE_REGISTRATION -DSUPPORT_SELECTIVE_REGISTRATION"
```

If you want to speed things up edit compile_ios_tensorflow.sh in the /Makefile directory. Look for the following line:

```
BUILD_TARGET="i386 x86_64 armv7 armv7s arm64"
```

and change it to:

```
BUILD_TARGET="x86_64 arm64"
```