# How to Deploy trained TensorFlow 2.0 models using Amazon SageMaker?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

i am trying to deploy a custom trained tensorflow model using Amazon SageMaker. i have trained xlm roberta using tf 2.2.0 for multilingual sentiment analysis task.(please refer to this notebook : https://www.kaggle.com/mobassir/understanding-cross-lingual-models)
now, using trained weight file of my model i am trying to deploy that in sagemaker, i was following this tutorial : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/deploy-trained-keras-or-tensorflow-models-using-amazon-sagemaker/

converted some keras code from there to tensorflow.keras for 2.2.0
but when i do : **!ls export/Servo/1/variables** i can see that export as Savedmodel generating empty variables directory like this : https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1988

i can't find any documentation help for tf 2.2.0 trained model deployment

need example like this : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/deploy-trained-keras-or-tensorflow-models-using-amazon-sagemaker/ for tf 2.x models and not keras

even though **!ls export/Servo/1/variables** shows empty directory but An endpoint was created successfully and now i am not sure if my model was deployed successfully or not because when i try to test the model deployment inside aws notebook by using predictor = sagemaker.tensorflow.model.TensorFlowPredictor(endpoint_name, sagemaker_session)
i.e. predictor.predict(data) i get the following error message:

```
ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (400) from model with message "{
    "error": "Session was not created with a graph before Run()!"
}"
```

related problem : [Inference error with TensorFlow C++ on iOS: "Invalid argument: Session was not created with a graph before Run()!"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46201109/inference-error-with-tensorflow-c-on-ios-invalid-argument-session-was-not-c)

the code i tried can be found here : https://pastebin.com/sGuTtnSD

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem. The AWS documentation is for tf1 and causes that error. If you figured out a solution please share!

Comment: i've solved everything,here is step by step procedure : https://github.com/mobassir94/Deploy-trained-TensorFlow-2.x-models-using-Amazon-SageMaker/blob/main/How_to_deploy_custom_tf_2_x_model_using_aws_sagemaker.ipynb

Comment: I got it working, thank you for sharing!